# Replace string in a file using batch script. I have the below code but it's adding blank space at the end of each line

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

Replace string in a file using batch script. I have the below code but it's adding blank space at the end of each line. It is affecting the job process while loading. Is there any easy way to replace like replace in notepad?

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "search=%Old text"
set "replace=%new text"
set txtfile=D:\new_%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-4,4%.txt
set newfile=D:\new_D%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-4,4%_T%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%%time:~-5,2%.txt
if exist "%newfile%" del /f /q "%newfile%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%txtfile%) do (
set newline=%%a
set newline=!newline:%search%=%replace%!
echo !newline! >> %newfile%

)
copy %newfile% %textfile%
```

Comment: Because you are echoing a space to the file.  Remove the space before the redirection.

Comment: `>> %newfile% (echo !newline!)`

Comment: Why do you put `%` signs into `set "search=%Old text"` and `set "replace=%new text"`? they will be removed by the parser anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to replace this :

```
echo !newline! >> %newfile%
```

by this :

```
>>%newfile% echo !newline!
```

**EDIT**: You'll better use `(echo !newline!)` like proposed by `@MC ND`

**EDIT II** : If you want something quicker (for big file) use a BAT/Powershell

```
@echo off
setlocal
set $source=%cd%\out.txt
set $Dest=%cd%\out1.txt

set "search=Old"
set "replace=New"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -c "(get-content '%$source%') | foreach-object {$_ -replace '%Search%', '%replace%'} | set-content '%$dest%'"') do echo %%a
```

Comment: Thanks! Works good in both way, Is there any one line command to replace the string instead of using loops. Using loops is consuming bit more time.

Comment: Using 100% BAT no, you can use `Powershell` or `VBS` to do this quicker. Check my second EDIT. I made an example BAT/PowerShell.